# while incoming call to open system app phone dialer

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am setting the phone app as my default app and also getting the call inside the **onCallAdded() method**. but while incoming the call, should open android phone dialer, not my default dialer, **like truecaller or easycallbalcklist**

Service class

```
 public class TestConnectionService extends InCallService {
@Override
public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
    super.onCallAdded(call);
    Log.d("callservice","call came");
    }
}
```

MainActivity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
    intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

mainfest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".service.TestConnectionService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
            android:value="true" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking. if you set yourself as the default phone app *AND* implement InCallService then you're now in charge of displaying the in-call-ui, including the in-call-ui's dialer

Comment: thanks for reply,  i am agree with you, if i set the app as phone app default and implement inCallService then i have to show in-call-ui, now is it possible to show phone app dilaer while incoming call arrive on mobile, instead of showing my call-ui layout.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: did you find the solution?